# Unable to copy files to system drive during Provisioning Package deployment

Tags: windows, deployment

I've tried a couple different methods of copying some files from the Provisioning Package to the system drive. In the batch files attempts, it did create the log file as expected, meaning I know it has access to the %SystemDrive%.  What am I doing wrong? Or is there some other way to copy files?

Methods I tried:

1. PrimaryContext command

   ```
   CommandFile: c:\deploymentfiles\test.bat
   CommandLine: cmd /c test.bat
   ```
2. DeviceContext command

   ```
   CommandFile: c:\deploymentfiles\test.bat
   CommandLine: cmd /c test.bat
   ```

   > **test.bat**
   >
   > ```
   > @echo off
   > set LOGFILE=%SystemDrive%\logs\provisiontest.log
   > mkdir c:\logs >NUL 2>&1
   > copy test.txt %SystemDrive% >NUL 2>&1
   > echo Copy result: %ERRORLEVEL% >> %LOGFILE%
   > ```
3. PrimaryContext command

   ```
   CommandFile: c:\deploymentfiles\test.txt
   CommandLine: copy test.txt %SystemDrive%
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you specify `CommandFile: c:\deploymentfiles\test.txt`? You only show the .bat in your question.

Either way, `copy test.txt C:` without a trailing slash `\` will actually copy the file into the *current working directory* due to CMD's weird way of expanding drive letters. Use `copy test.txt "%systemdrive%\"` instead if you really need to dump something into the root of the drive (If possible, I'd recommend using `%temp%` or anything else instead).

And a final note that if you use `>> %LOGFILE% 2>&1` on your copy command instead of `>NUL 2>&1`, then your log file will actually show the errors

Comment: 1. I thought everything got put in `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Provisioning\` and relative paths would work. But you are saying it will mirror whatever folder structure I had on the PC where the package was built?
2. I want the logs to persist for now. But I will probably change the folder later.
3. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @THEJOATMON Two separate things: A) CMD interprets `C:` and `C:\ ` differently. B) I can't see your package, so I'm not sure you've added `test.txt` to it correctly. If you send the output of `copy` to your log file instead of just the 1 or 0 errorlevel, it will say `The system cannot find the file specified` if the source (test.txt) isn't where you expect, OR it should say `1 file(s) copied.` if the destination is valid (but maybe not where you expect).

Comment: I only glanced at the MS docs for this, but they do say "The CommandFile assets are deployed on the device to a temporary folder unique to each package". https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-itpro-docs/blob/public/windows/configuration/provisioning-packages/provisioning-script-to-install-app.md#remarks . I don't think the exact location is the issue with your script or anything, but it might be helpful to know if you're packaging apps this way

Answer (score 0):

Posting this for reference.  The code below works. The accepted answer from Cpt.Whale led me to this.

CommandFiles:

```
test:  c:\wherever\scripts\are\stored\test.txt
```

CommandLine:

```
cmd /c test.bat
```

> **test.bat**
>
> ```
> @echo off
> set LOGFILE=%SystemDrive%\Company\logs\provisiontest.log
> mkdir %SystemDrive%\Company>NUL 2>&1
> mkdir %SystemDrive%\Company\logs >NUL 2>&1
> mkdir %SystemDrive%\Company\scripts >> %LOGFILE% 2>&1
> dir >> %LOGFILE%
> copy test.txt %SystemDrive%\Company\scripts\ >> %LOGFILE%
> echo Copy result: %ERRORLEVEL% >> %LOGFILE%
> ```

As an aside, the `dir` command shows that the script is run from `c:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\appdata\local\temp\provisioningpkgTmp\{guid}\Commands`